# How to update value of cell of specific row when iterating with each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the values of the first column of a table and based on an if statement I need to update the value of the third column of each specific row.
This is what I do:

```
$("#attributes_tbl tr").each(function(){
  var value = $(this).find("td input:nth-child(2)").val();
  if (value in attribute_enumerations){
    description = attribute_enumerations[value]
    console.log(description)
    $('td:nth-child(3) input').val(description);
  }
});
```

The above snippet updates all the rows of the third column. What I need is to update the cell of the third column of the current row:

```
// I need this to update only the specific cell of the current row (from the "each" loop)
```

$('td:nth-child(3) input').val(description);

How can I specify this in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To affect only the current row, change:

```
$('td:nth-child(3) input').val(description);
```

To:

```
$(this).find('td:nth-child(3) input').val(description);
```